# Dynamically add fields to component's menu edit form

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, jform, custom-field

I am looking to add parameters to the edit-view of my component's menu editor on the fly instead of statically defining them as you normally would (as described : https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_variable_request_in_the_menu_type ).

I have created a plugin and implemented onContentPrepareForm.  Within the plugin I construct xml for fields with the name "params" so that this data will be stored in the [params] column for the menu.

The parameters are shown just fine on the form, however the data is not saved.  I have traced this through the bowels of the JForm joomla code and it turns out the JForm framework is discarding all of the custom fields that have been added dynamically.

*** Specifically (and this is where I need help) *** 
JModelForm::validate() calls JForm::validate() calls JForm::findFieldsByGroup().  This last call eliminates my custom fields.  If I comment out the first call to validate(), the data for my custom fields is stored.

Here's a sample of my plugin showing how I add the XML on the fly.

```
public function onContentPrepareForm( $form, $data)
{
$option = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('option');
$view = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('view');

$modifyForm = false;

// check if this is a menu item for my component
if($option == 'com_menus' && $view == 'item' && array_key_exists('component_id', $data))
{
$myComponent = JComponentHelper::getComponent('com_mycomponent');
if($data['component_id'] == $myComponent->id)
{   
$modifyForm = true;
}
}

if($modifyForm)
{
            $testXml = '<fields name="params">
                            <fieldset name="basic" label="FIELDSET-LABEL">
                                <field name="test-field" type="list" label="test-field-label" description="test-field-description">
                                <option value="">Default</option>
                                <option value="0">Zero</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                </field>
                            </fieldset>
                    </fields>';
            $xmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($testXml);
            $form->setField($xmlElement);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to note that [the same question was asked](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&hl=en#!topic/joomla-dev-general/K7fA6KAoQPM) by @ajhuddy in Joomla! General Development maillist and it has an answer.

> **** SOLVED ****
>
> (Thanks Hannes for leading me to the answer)
>
> It seems to be key in the `onContentPrepareForm` part of the plugin to
>   only make a change to the form if `$form->getName()` evaluates to the
>   form you are wanting to alter.

Comment: Yes that was me I should have updated this question